# GitLab default url not secure

Tags: html, git, ssl, gitlab

I'm trying to set up a Gitlab Page to host my personal site (CV, code examples that sort of thing) with the standard `userName.gitlab.io` domain.
At the moment it's just a HelloWorld in `index.html` and `readme.md` I pushed to check it's all working, (and it is).

The problem is when I access the site through https on Firefox I get :

> This site uses HTTP Strict Transport Security (HSTS).

The advanced message

> mr.brompton.gitlab.io uses an invalid security certificate. The certificate is only valid for the following names: *.gitlab.io, gitlab.io Error code: SSL_ERROR_BAD_CERT_DOMAIN

I can access through Chrome but only with http. All of the documentation I have read suggests https should work automatically. Again I feel I'm missing something stupid. Perhaps I should just add my own cert?

The repo can be found @ `mr.brompton.gitlab.io` or `gitlab.com/mr.brompton`

my config yaml:

```
  # Full project: https://gitlab.com/pages/plain-html
pages:
  stage: deploy
  script:
  - mkdir .public
  - cp -r * .public
  - mv .public public
artifacts:
  paths:
  - public
only:
  - master
```

Answer (score 5):

The answer was something simple as I suspected. The project was named `mr.brompton` which meant my domain was `mr.brompton.gitlab.io`. The certificate is valid for `*.gitlab.io`. This meant the cert was returning invalid after trying to find `gitlab.io` after the `mr.*`. I fixed the problem by changing my user name, project path and project name to `mr-brompton`. I will also change the url's, username and all other associations on my local machine.

Comment: Official ticket: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-com/gl-infra/infrastructure/issues/3268 The conclusion seems that this problem is unsolvable. The only solution is to not choose a username containing a dot.

Comment: Thank you, this fixed my problem as well

Comment: Thank you for sharing the answer.